# Proving that every $x \in \mathbb Z_{20}$ satisfies $x^4 - 10x^2 + 9 \equiv 0 \mod 20$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Could you help me with the problem below?

> Prove that for every $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{20}$ we have $x^4 - 10x^2 + 9 \equiv 0 \mod 20$.

Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't matter much here, because the number of cases is small. But still, by reflex, work modulo $4$ and then modulo $5$.

Answer (score 2):

I think that with $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ you mean $(\mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z})^*$, i.e. all integers $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\text{gcd}(z,2)=\text{gcd}(z,5)=1$. Now $$p(x):=x^4-10x^2+9=(x-3)(x-1)(x+1)(x+3)$$. Since $\{-3,-1,1,3\}$ is a whole non zero residue system in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ then $5\mid p(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{Z}$. Moreover, since $z$ is odd by construction then $$2\mid \text{gcd}(z-3,z-1,z+1,z+3)$$ showing that $2^4 \mid p(z)$ for all odd integer $z$. We can do even better!

The set $\{z-3,z-1,z+1,z+3\}$ represents four consecutive even integers, so two of them will be divisible exactly by $2$, and the other ones at least by $4$ and $8$, i.e. $$\upsilon_2(p(z)) \ge 7 \text{ for all } z \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus 2\mathbb{Z}$$
where $\upsilon_p(m)$ is the $p$-adic valutation of a integer $m$, given a prime $p$.

Moreover, since $2$ is coprime with $3$ and $\{z-3,z-1,z+1\} \subset \{z-3,z-1,z+1,z+3\}$ then $3\mid p(z)$ for all integers $z \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now, $\text{gcd}(7,20)=1$, and $p(7)=4\cdot 6 \cdot 8 \cdot 10 = 2^7 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$. We have just shown that the maximum greatest common divisor between all numbers of the form $p(z)$ with $\text{gcd}(z,20)=1$ is **exactly** $2^7 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$.

Answer (score 2):

$\rm\ mod\ 5\!:\ f(x) \equiv x^4\!-\!1\equiv 0\!\iff\! x\not\equiv 0,\:$ by $\mu$-Fermat (or $\{0,\pm1,\pm2\}^4\!\equiv \{0,1,-1\}^2\!\equiv\{0,1,1\})$
$\rm\:mod\ 4\!:\ f(x)\equiv (x^2\!-\!1)^2\!\equiv 0\!\iff\!x\equiv \pm1\!\iff\! x\:$ odd.

Comment: What is $\mu$-Fermat?

Comment: *Micro* Fermat, a.k.a. the [*little* Fermat theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem)

Comment: Hahaha! I guessed, but I was curious to ask! It is not standard notation =) I know you have a thing for not wasting too many letters, though.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^4 - 10x^2 + 9 = (x^2-1)(x^2-9)$$
Now $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{20}^* \implies x \equiv \pm 1, \pm3, \pm7, \pm 9 \pmod{20}$. This means $x^2 \equiv 1,9 \pmod{20}$. Hence, if $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{20}^*$, then either $(x^2-1) \equiv 0 \pmod{20}$ or $(x^2-9) \equiv 0  \pmod{20}$. Hence for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{20}^*$,
$$x^4 - 10x^2 + 9 = (x^2-1)(x^2-9) \equiv 0 \pmod{20}$$

Comment: Thank you very very much...!

Comment: The OP wrote $\,\Bbb Z_{20}\,$ , not $\,\Bbb Z_{20}^*\,$ , though I think he well may have meant the latter. Why though he hasn't corrected his post or else remarked the above doesn't cover all the possi8ilities?

Comment: That's just a typo. If a integer $z$ is even then $p(z)$ is odd (i.e. not multiple of $20$), and if $5\mid z$ then $p(z) \equiv -1 \pmod 5$, i.e. not multiple of $20$ again. So $z \in (\mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z})^*$ is a necessary and sufficient condition so that $20 \mid p(z)$. And, as I have shown below, it's also a necessary and sufficient condition such that $$2^7\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \mid p(z)\text{ whenever }\text{gcd}(z,10)=1$$ (and noone greater integer can be substituted).

Comment: @DonAntonio The OP's original question had $Z20^*$ in the statement (but not in the title). Now the edit has removed the $^*$.